# Why does one of these listeners work for a Media API event but not the other?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm adding a listener for a Media API event as follows:

```
function addPlayListener() {
    var video = document.getElementById("theVideo");
    video.addEventListener('play',  function() {alert('play');}, false); // method a
video.addEventListener('play',  alert('play'), false); // method b
}
window.addEventListener('load', addPlayListener, false);


<video id="theVideo" controls width="180" height="160" src="sample_mpeg4.mp4"> </video>
```

Using method a everything works as expected, however using method b the alert is displayed as soon as the page loads (and doesn't display when the event fires).

Why is this, is there something wrong with the syntax for method b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [addEvenListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) documentation:

```
 target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
```

`listener` must be:

- object, implementing the `EventListener` interface,
- JavaScript function

`alert()` function does not return any object, which implements `EventListener` interface, nor Javascript `function`. Simply, `alert` does not return anything. So, what you get is:

```
  video.addEventListener('play',  undefined , false);   //method b
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) must be "the object that receives a notification when an event of the specified type occurs. This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, or simply a JavaScript function." In your "method b" the alert is triggered immediatly because it is not within a function, nor is it an object implementing the EventListener interface. method A is the commonly accepted syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In `method b`, the dialog is displaying immediately because you're calling it first -- `alert('play')`. `addEventListener` can't delay the execution of its arguments and is instead being passed the `alert`'s `return` value -- which it can't do much with:

```
// what's being passed after `alert('play')` is called
video.addEventListener('play', true, false);
```

The `function () { ... }` in `method a` is exactly what you need to delay the call of `alert('play')` until the event is triggered. The a function itself is being passed to `addEventListener`, and can be called any number of times later (i.e. with each trigger of the event). And, with each call, it will in turn execute its contents.